# Socket. Отловить обрыв связи

Tags: android, сокет

Как отловить ошибки сокетов? Например, обрыв связи...

Answer (score 3):

По поводу обрывов связи:
Сокет работает таким образом, что если в данный момент нет обмена данных (через InputStream и OutputStream), то сокет не сможет обнаружить обрыв связи. Для того, чтобы он обнаружил, что на другом конце произошел обрыв, необходимо послать на другую сторону какой нибудь acknowlegment. Просто отправить любой символ в OutputStream сокета. Тогда, если произошел обрыв звязи, операция бросит Exception.

Из того, что было у меня, я воспользовался таким приемом:

```
int delay = 1000;
socket.getInetAddress().isReachable(delay);
```

данная строка проверяет доступен ли адрес, к которому подключен сокет.

Кроме того, следует быть осторожным с OutputStream. У меня бывало так, что Exception не вылетал, но тем не менее при обращению к BufferedReader, который читал OutputStream readLine() выдавал null. Потому в таком случае я просто прерывал обработку и пробовал переподключить сокет.

Вопрос очень хороший, поскольку у меня у самого часто возникали подобные проблемы и решение я собирал по кусочкам из постов на SO. Вот мой код из программы клиента, а точнее треда обработчика, которая работает в локальной сети:

```
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (!mSocket.getInetAddress().isReachable(5000))
                    return;

                String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(message == null)
                    return;
                // тут я обрабатываю сообщение после проверок
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } finally {
            quietClose(bufferedReader);
            quietClose(inputStreamReader);
            try {
                if (mSocket != null)
                    mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }
```

Для серера это выглядит примерно так же.

Возможно так же отправить acknowlegment вручную:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println(ACK); // ACK - любой символ
    if (out.checkError()) {
         //обработать ошибку
```

Еще один способ, проверить обрыв. Если read() на InputStream возвращает -1.

Прошу не судить строго, поскольку все вышеописанное, это просто примеры из личного опыта.